# Hibernate 5.x memory leak - looks like HQL queries caching?

Tags: java, hibernate, memory-leaks

We have a bog standard REST-based Hibernate application.

Recently we noticed that it dies the death by `Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded` time and again. We've emulated what happens there in a test, that collects items from a collection of elements. After about 1000 runs the application goes kaput with the pattern as below. The production displays similar behavior, although the time scale is much longer:

[image]

Java profiler shows the abundance of hibernate `Node` elements in a hashmap:

[image]

When drilling deeper into the what these nodes are I can see the following:

[image]

It looks like Hibernate caches HQL queries (even if we run the same query over and over again).

The class that comprises the offending collection is below:

```
@Entity
@Audited
@Table(name = "benefit_package", uniqueConstraints = {
        @UniqueConstraint(name = "uk01_benefit_package", columnNames = {"employer_guid", "benefit_package_name"}),
        @UniqueConstraint(name = "uk02_benefit_package", columnNames = {"benefit_package_guid"})})
@SequenceGenerator(name = "benefit_package_sequence", sequenceName = "benefit_package_id_seq", allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = {"employerId", "name"})
@ToString(of = {"id", "employerId", "name"})
public class BenefitPackage {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "benefit_package_id")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "benefit_package_sequence", strategy = SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "benefit_package_guid", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "binary(16)")
    private UUID guid;

    @Column(name = "benefit_package_name", nullable = false)
    private String name;

    @Column(name = "employer_guid", nullable = false, columnDefinition = "binary(16)")
    private UUID employerId;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "selection_control_id")
    private SelectionControl selectionControl;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "benefitPackage")
    private List<BenefitPackageVersion> versions = new ArrayList<>();

    @Column(name = "last_modified_date")
    private LocalDateTime lastModifiedDate;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "optlock")
    private Long optLock;
```

This entity is used with pagination, but we do not use any custom JPA queries (at least overtly) for this operation.

Application details: SpringBoot 1.2.8, Hibernate 5.1 (Upgrading to 5.2.18Final had no effect). No second level cache is used.

**Questions:**

1. Why should Hibernate cache the same query over and over again?
2. Has this ever been noticed or addressed? Is there a fix for this problem?

I know the ticket might be a duplication, but I have not found definitive answer to that question anywhere.

Comment: I need more information.  You do not show the entire BenefitPackage class, so I do not know what methods the class has, if any.  Also, I do not see the code this using the BenefitPackage class.